# How to highlight the axis?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I have many axes in the chart.

How to highlight the axis when hovering on a line(axis-value)?

It is necessary to highlight the axis to which the line(axis-value) belongs (when hovering on a line(axis-value))

(Highlight = make bold or change color)

Sorry for the bad english :)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the seriesHover event:

```
seriesHover: function(e) {
    var axis = e.sender.getAxis( e.series.axis);
    for (var i=0; i<e.sender.options.valueAxis.length; i++){
        if (i ==axis._axis.axisIndex){
            e.sender.options.valueAxis[i].line.width = 3;
        } else {
            e.sender.options.valueAxis[i].line.width = 1;
        }                   
    }
    e.sender.refresh();
}
```

From the series you can get theassociated axis, then set the axis line width and refresh the chart.

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/aJRJGL)**

Comment: @enot, here is a fix: http://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/aJRJGL  only refresh the chart if the correct axis is not already highlighted...